# How can I accept invalid or self-signed SSL certificates in Rust futures reqwest?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio, reqwest

My code looks like the following:

```rust
let fetches = futures::stream::iter(
    hosts.into_iter().map(|url| {
        async move {
                match reqwest::get(&url).await {
                    // Ok and Err statements here!
                }
```

But, the problem here is that it gives an error for URLs with invalid or self-signed SSL certificate. So, I tried to do the following:

```rust
let fetches = futures::stream::iter(
    hosts.into_iter().map(|url| {
        async move {
            match reqwest::Client::builder().danger_accept_invalid_certs(true).build().unwrap().get(&url).await {
                // Ok and Err statements here!
            }
```

When I try to build it with Cargo, it says "*error[E0277]: `RequestBuilder` is not a future*".

So, how can I make my code accept invalid certificates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike the top-level [`get()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.0/reqwest/fn.get.html) function, which returns a `Response`, the [`Client::get()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.0/reqwest/struct.Client.html#method.get) method which you call in the second snippet, returns a [`RequestBuilder`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.0/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html), which you must [`send()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.0/reqwest/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.send) to actually communicate.

Adding the missing `send()` allows the code to compile ([playgropund](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=98b815c820d6d6a354a9dc1043743b9a)):

```
fn main() {
    let hosts: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let fetches = futures::stream::iter(hosts.into_iter().map(|url| async move {
        match reqwest::Client::builder()
            .danger_accept_invalid_certs(true)
            .build()
            .unwrap()
            .get(&url)
            .send()
            .await
        {
            Ok(x) => x,
            Err(x) => panic!(),
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked for me as the code compiled. However, I am still unable to solve my major problem of accepting URLs with invalid or self-signed SSL certificates. Is there any idea regarding this?

Comment: @BinitGhimire I would expect accept_invalid_certs to fix that. If it doesn't, you might want to raise an issue at the [project issue tracker](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest).