# How to resolve a Rust Reqwest Error: Invalid Certificate

Tags: rust, https, tls1.2, reqwest, rust-warp

Quick question, does reqwest allow self-signed certificates? I have created a tls enabled rust-warp webserver. And I have created a reqwest client to make requests to this server for testing purposes. The cert added to `add_root_certificate` is the same certificate which the server is using. It's odd because when I use other clients such as Python or CURL there are no issues making the requests, and I do not get a TLS error on my server.

Here's my sample rust code:

```
let mut buf = Vec::new();
File::open("my_cert.pem")?
  .read_to_end(&mut buf)?;
let cert = reqwest::Certificate::from_pem(&buf)?;
let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
  .add_root_certificate(cert)
  .build()?;

let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("name", "John");

let res = client.post("https://IP:PORT/endpoint").json(&map).send().await?;
```

And here's my sample Python code:

```
path_to_cert = "path/to/cert/my_cert.pem"
route = "https://IP:PORT/endpoint"
payload = {
"name": "John",
}
res = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), verify=path_to_cert)
```

Not sure what is causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

I have built a rust-warp server, and I am posting data to it for testing. I expect my rust-request to successfully post data to my server, but my server logs:

TLS alert received AlertMessagePayload {
level: Fatal,
description: CertificateUnknown,
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I accept invalid or self-signed SSL certificates in Rust futures reqwest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977261/how-can-i-accept-invalid-or-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-rust-futures-reqwest)

Comment: @cafce25 it seems the answer there resolved an issue unrelated to the title (OP missing `.send()`) and in the comments said the cert issue persisted :/

Comment: adding .danger_accept_invalid_cert(true) worked. But I am not sure why I need this, because other clients such as CURL and Python requests have no problems making HTTPs requests with the same cert I am adding to reqwest using  .add_root_certificate(cert)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug: https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/1260

You'll need to use `rustls-tls` as your tls backend for now.

`cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11.24", features = ["blocking", "rustls-tls"] }
```

`main.rs`

```rust
let client = reqwest::blocking::ClientBuilder::new().add_root_certificate(ca_cert)
    .use_rustls_tls()
    .build()?;
```